# In Atom Editor: How to remain inside sidebar focus while navigating through tree using arrowskeys

Tags: atom-editor

I can open the TreeView with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>  (Linux/Windows) and get focus.  At this point I can navigate around with the arrow keys on the keyboard, but only by hitting enter and losing focus, am I able to see the file which was selected.

Is there a way to remain focused on the TreeView and with arrow key navigation enabled, and as each new file is navigated over, the editor will automatically switch to that tab or open a new tab with that file open?

The functionality would be similar to the [synced-sidebar Package](https://atom.io/packages/synced-sidebar) except in the opposite direction, i.e., you would navigate the TreeView with the arrow keys and the tab view would change instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and Welcome to the [tag:atom-editor] tag, I have reformatted your post to use some of the markup that Stack Overflow offers such as the `<kbd>` tag, I also took the opportunity to convert the link to an inline link please have a look at the [ask] page to see some of the other ways that Stack Overflow helps us ask great questions.

Comment: I don't know if there is an option to stay focused. But when you lost focus by hitting the enter key, you can use alt-\ or ctrl-0 on Mac which toggles the TreeView's focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [A. Campbell's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964389/7023209) doesn't seem to work; it's called on right-arrow press, but doesn't appear to do anything.

For others ending up here searching for a solution, there's [a long-opened github issue with a working answer](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/834) by ThomasChef.

Put this in your *init.coffee*: (mind the spaces...)

```coffee
atom.commands.add '.tree-view', 'custom:expand-item-down': ->
  fs = require 'fs'
  item = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem()
  atom.commands.dispatch(item.element, 'core:move-down')
  if fs.lstatSync(item.selectedPath).isDirectory()
    return
  else
    item.openSelectedEntry(pending: true, activatePane: false)
    return
atom.commands.add '.tree-view', 'custom:expand-item-up': ->
  fs = require 'fs'
  item = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem()
  atom.commands.dispatch(item.element, 'core:move-up')
  if fs.lstatSync(item.selectedPath).isDirectory()
    return
  else
    item.openSelectedEntry(pending: true, activatePane: false)
    return
```

and put this in your *keymap.cson*:

```coffee
'.tree-view':
  'down': 'custom:expand-item-down',
  'up': 'custom:expand-item-up'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following code to your `init.coffee` file:

```
atom.commands.add '.tree-view', 'tree-view:preview', ->
    for panel in atom.workspace.getLeftPanels()
        if panel.item.constructor.name == "TreeView"
            entry = panel.item.selectedEntry()
            if entry.classList[0] == "directory"
              entry.toggleExpansion()
              return
            else
              atom.workspace.open(entry.getPath(), pending: true, activatePane: false)
              return
```

After which you can set the code to execute by adding a new keymap to the `keymap.cson` file, like so:

```
'.tree-view':
  'right': 'tree-view:preview'
```

Using the right arrow will open files and directories in the tree view without moving focus to the editor. I'd suggest using enter to toggle focus once you're ready to edit a file.

Answer (score 0):

For toggle open & close sidebar tree view <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

For move focus around sidebar and editor page <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Tested on Atom for GNU/Linux.

I'm so sorry if my answer not related with your question.

[image]